# How to find multiples of numbers under a certain range

Tags: arithmetic, education

I recently found a 'question' that requires me to find the sum of all multiples of 3 and 5 under 1000, I sadly cheated and found some code online to help build a code in python:

```
sum=0
for i in range(999):
        if not(i %3 == 0) or not (i % 5):
                sum=sum+i
print sum
```

However, even though it works, I feel guilty that I had to cheat to answer this question. I do not understand what the if not means, and why I cannot use the regular if statement. Can someone please clear this up for me? Thanks waco001

P.S. In other languages like C, this:

```
int problem1()
{
    int sum=0;

    for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
    {
        if(i%3 == 0 || i%5 == 0)
        {
            sum+=i ;
        }
    }

    return sum ;
}
```

Works perfectly?!?

Comment: Doesn't your first code sum the numbers that *aren't* multiples of $3$ and $5$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Exactly! Thats why I am confused. The answer was right, but I'm pretty sure that the code should not have an 'if not' in it only an 'if' statement. That makes sense to me. Also, in the second example in C, an if statment was used, not an IF NOT.

Comment: To be clear, you want to sum multiples of 3 **or** 5, correct?  Multiples of 3 **and** 5 are just multiples of 15.

Comment: @SammyBlack Yes

Comment: Note that your python code has an expression which will not evaluate to a boolean value: `or not (1 % 5)`. Perhaps that is just an oversight in your post here. But, importanly, the *negation* of `x || y` is `not x & not y`

Comment: I think the "not" code works because of the coincidence that the numbers you want add up to the same as the numbers you don't want. E.g., if we were going up to $15$, instead of $1000$, then $3+5+6+9+10+12+15=60=1+2+4+7+8+11+13+14$.

Comment: Is it a problem here? http://projecteuler.net/problem=1

Answer (score 2):

You don't need such a brute force calculation.  You can do this by hand.  First, some notation.  Let
$$
M_3 = 3\mathbb{Z} \cap [1, 999] = \{ \text{multiples of 3 between 1 and 999, inclusive} \}
$$
This definition works for any $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.  The quantity that you are looking for is
$$
S = \sum_{n \in M_3 \cup M_5} n
$$

Which numbers are in $M_3 \cup M_5$?  Multiples of $3$ or $5$, of course, but you must be careful.  Multiples of $15 = 3 \cdot 5$ are multiples of both $3$ and $5$.  In fact, $M_3 \cap M_5 = M_{15}$, so
$$
\begin{align}
S &= \sum_{n \in M_3} n + \sum_{n \in M_5} n - \sum_{n \in M_{15}} n \\
\end{align}
$$
I will show you how to calculate one of these sums.  (The other two are strictly analogous.)  Consider
$$
\sum_{n \in M_3} n = 3 + 6 + \cdots + 996 + 999
$$
How many summands are there?  $\left\lfloor \frac{999}{3} \right\rfloor = \left\lfloor 333 \right\rfloor = 333$.  Thus, [by pairing terms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum) à la [Aryabhata](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aryabhatiya) (and [famously](http://www.sigmaxi.org/amscionline/gauss-snippets.html) young K.F. Gauss), you have
$$
\sum_{n \in M_3} n = \frac{333(3 + 999)}{2} = 166\,833.
$$

Comment: How do you find the first multiple? In this case `3`.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job :

```
numberOfDivisors = (end / actualNumber) - ((start - 1 ) / actualNumber)
```

**Note** : start, end are inclusive.

Answer (score -1):

For a range $(n, m)$ both inclusive,number of multiples of a number $x$ can be 
calculated as $x = (m-n+1)/(given \ number)$